# Stray "\303" and stray "\215" in program -- why?

Tags: c

Instead of stray "\302" in a program which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167656/error-stray-302-in-program), I got the error message:

```
algo.c:118: error: stray ‘\303’ in program
algo.c:118: error: stray ‘\215’ in program
```

I could not seem to figure it out. What is this?

---

For future reference, stray '\XXX' means an incomprehensible character to the compiler. The way to fix is to find the '\XXX' character (which now I find out is not always this Unicode. It can't be a wrong definition, such as '##' in '##define'), so delete or correct it. Good luck!

Comment: Was this copied from Windows to Linux? What about the command `dos2unix`, have you tried that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6526863/2591612

Comment: One reason could be that you have non-ASCII characters in your variable names. Visual Studio allows those, but not GCC.

Comment: If you are on Linux/Unix/Mac OSX, try typing "cat -vet algo.c" to see off characters.

Comment: You can look at line 118 in your file `algo.c` to find the problem. Maybe also post it to make your question understandable?

Comment: This is very odd, because when I was editing it in vim, every line of code looks just fine. But then I was trying to edit it in sublime text 2. All of the sudden there is an unknown latin character shown in the end of line 118. I think it was just hidden while in vim or something. But thank you very much!

Comment: Can you post the offending code, please?

Comment: As [noted in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22384338/stray-303-and-stray-215-in-program-why?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment34071742_22389604), 303 215 (octal) → 0xC3 0x8D (hexadecimal) → UTF-8 sequence for Unicode code point U+00CD ([LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH ACUTE](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=200)).

Comment: I can reproduce this problem with the Unicode character `Í` (UTF-8 encoded). With [GCC 7.5.0](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-7/) (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04), 2019-11-14 (yes, I know).

Comment: UTF-8 sequences starting with 303 (octal) are not uncommon. Another one observed in the wild is 303 244 (octal)   → 0xC3 0xA4 (hexadecimal) → UTF-8 sequence for Unicode code point U+00E4 ([LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=224)). That is `ä`. I can't find the reference at this point, but I have [registered it](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2023/05/01/unicode-blues-in-c-and-similar-languages-after-copying-from-web-pages-skype-chat-etc/).

Comment: On some keyboard layouts, `Í` can be accidentally typed by hitting the key inbetween "+" and [backspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backspace). And then Shift + I.

Comment: There isn't any need to search for it visually. It can be searched (and replaced) for by using the regular expression `\x{00CD}` in any modern text editor or IDE. Note: The notation is different in Visual Studio Code (and probably others): `\u00CD` (instead of `\x{00CD}`)

Comment: A greater range of common stray characters, incl. some ***invisible*** (e.g. ZERO WIDTH SPACE) and ***visually identical*** (e.g., non-breaking space), can be searched for by regular expression `\x{00A0}|\x{00A6}|\x{00AB}|\x{00AE}|\x{00BB}|\x{00CD}|\x{00E4}|\x{2003}|\x{2009}|\x{200B}|\x{200C}|\x{2013}|\x{2014}|\x{2018}|\x{2019}|\x{201C}|\x{201D}|\x{2028}|\x{2029}|\x{202A}|\x{202B}|\x{202C}|\x{2060}|\x{21B5}|\x{2212}|\x{2217}|\x{2260}|\x{FEFF}|\x{FF1A}|\x{FFFC}|\x{FFFD}`

Comment: The canonical question is *[Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332/)*

Comment: OK, the OP has left the building: *"Last seen more than 5 years ago"*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are:

```
00C3    LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH TILDE
        : 0041 0303
        U+00C3, character Ã‬, decimal 195, hex 0xC3, octal \303, binary 11000011
        UTF-8: 0xc3 0x83

008D    <control>
        = REVERSE LINE FEED
        U+008D, character ‬, decimal 141, hex 0x8D, octal \215, binary 10001101
        UTF-8: 0xc2 0x8d
```

I'm guessing those aren't there deliberately. Sometimes editing in a terminal can produce this if you start typing before the window has fully loaded and done its `stty` thing. I often see this sort of thing in `emacs`.

Solution: go to the appropriate lines and remove the characters. `cat -te` or `less` are useful for identifying which characters are problematic.

Comment: Easiest is normally to edit the file, retype the offending line exactly as shown below it, and deleting the original with (invisible) garbage in it.

Comment: It was a character that was not shown in vim but appeared in sublime text 2. I think I might have mistakenly typed this in and forgot it because the length of the code.

Comment: But my fix was simply to delete the latin capital letter. I did not see reverse line feed char tho. Is that because it just automatically come with a latin character?

Comment: In UTF-8 the sequence 0xC3 0x8D represents the single character [U+00CD LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH ACUTE](http://codepoints.net/U+00CD) which is probably what you saw.

Answer (score 0):

As an additional answer, it happens to me a lot when I want to type characters that requires an [<kbd>AltGr</kbd>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key) key combination. Usually my fingers slipped and it results in hidden garbage character.

As said, a better solution is to rewrite the spotted line.

Answer (score 0):

Using non-ASCII characters in code may cause these errors.

I had the same issue using öäü... in an `enum`.

Comment: Re *"in an enum"*: But those ***are*** [allowed by the standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692067/and-other-unicode-characters-in-identifiers-not-allowed-by-g), but [GCC did not catch up before version 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692067/and-other-unicode-characters-in-identifiers-not-allowed-by-g/42158646#42158646) (May 2020).

Comment: Yes, the UTF-8 sequence for [ä](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=224) also starts with 303 (octal. hexadecimal C3), like in this question.