# ERROR stray \327 C code not compiling

Tags: c, gcc, lfsr

This c code from a book on applied cryptography will not compile

```html
int LFSR () {
static unsigned long ShiftRegister = 1;
/* Anything but 0. */
ShiftRegister = ((((ShiftRegister >> 31)
^ (ShiftRegister >> 6)
^ (ShiftRegister >> 4)
^ (ShiftRegister >> 2)
^ (ShiftRegister >> 1)
^ ShiftRegister))
& 0×00000001)
<< 31)
| (ShiftRegister >> 1) ;
return ShiftRegister & 0×00000001;
}
```

and there  is no obvious mistake on it

Comment: Did you paste it from a web page or something like Microsoft word? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22384338/stray-303-and-stray-215-in-program-why  Look very carefully at the x that isn't an x... `0×00000001`

Comment: When you copy/paste code from an electronic source (web, PDF, or whatever) you have to be careful that the characters you see are the characters you get. In this case, FBergo is right: the 'x' isn't a letter 'x', it's a Unicode multiplication symbol.

Comment: Note: \327 == 215 = 0xD7

Comment: Thank you everyone for the helpful feedback so there were two mistakes the Unicode as a mentioned in the thread and a missing parenthesis

Answer (score 4):

In the hexadecimal constants, those should be `x` (lower case letter X), not `×` (multiplication sign).

Comment: [Unicode Character 'MULTIPLICATION SIGN'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/d7/index.htm)